# Strange white screen with lines before login screen - Garuda Linux

Tags: linux, display, xorg

Since I’ve been using Linux, specifically Garuda Linux, I’ve seen this strange white screen (check images below).

It usually appears for 1~2 seconds or even less when I turn on, before the login screen, and sometimes when I shutdown, also super quickly.

My windowing system is X11.

I wonder if it’s normal behavior. Even though I don’t think so, I wander if it could be somehow potentially harmful to my monitor or graphics card.

[image: white screen with colorful horizontal lines]

Comment: No, not harmful.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the clarification. Just thought it was bizarre, but happy to know that is not really harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar experience, though without citation…

It's a graphics driver issue - or rather a 'driver not loaded yet' issue. I see similar on my Mac during boot [though not so severe]. In my case I know it's because the GPU is non-standard for the model [even though it is correctly flashed for Mac] & so without drivers things are a bit random.
It clears before I get to the login screen & is only ever seen before the boot sequence completes.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for sharing, it's basically what happens here too.
Do you know if it's harmful by any means?

Comment: The computer is from 2012, the GPU from around 2016… no problems so far ;))